# Healthbars in Phaser 3

Tags: phaser-framework

I am making a top down zombie shooter in Phaser 3.

I am using the moveToObject function to make zombies follow the player. Now I want to make healthbars for the zombies. I have read that you can use containers to make the enemies and healthbars move together but I am having trouble to move the container with moveToObject.

Is it possible to move a container with the moveToObject function or should I use something else instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `moveToObject` method looks for an individual item's velocity and according to the [API Docs](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.GameObjects.Container.html), Container doesn't hold an overall velocity. But each object added to the container should have a velocity.

The quick way to fix this is to iterate through your container's objects and tell each item to moveToObject. I'm adapting an example from [Phaser Labs](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Cphysics%5Carcade%5Cmove%20to.js) here:

```
var block = this.physics.add.image(600, 300, 'block');
var clown2 = this.physics.add.image(20, 200, 'clown');
var clown = this.physics.add.image(200, 300, 'clown');
var container = this.add.container(10, 200, [clown, clown2]);


for (var x = 0; x < container.list.length; x++) {
  this.physics.moveToObject(container.list[x], destination, 200);
}
```

This might not be the cleanest solution but it should help accomplish what you want to do. The Phaser API docs say moveToObject works with a GameObject, which includes Container. This might be worth reporting as a bug to see if there is a way the base code can be fixed to allow containers to work. You can report the issue [here](https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser/issues) if you'd like.